# How to hide Matlab Command Window and command prompt from calling system in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I execute the Matlab script file using system() which uses the command prompt and it's working fine. But i wish to hide everything and hope it runs in the background and only showing my GUI from the script file. Any idea?

This is my command in MSVS C++ (Note : i cut short the path name for simplicity purposes) :

```
system("\"\"C:\\matlab.exe\" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r \"run('C:\\main.m');\"\"");
```

Comment: I see no reason to use `system` here. You could try `CreateProcess` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You might try: system("start \b \"\"C:\\matlab.exe\" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r \"run('C:\\main.m');\"\"");

Comment: @DieterLücking, "the system could not find the file " =(

Comment: @ooga, ok thx i'll have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You could try `CreateProcess` instead of `system`. A simple example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  STARTUPINFO si = {
    sizeof(si),
    NULL, NULL, NULL,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
  };

  BOOL res = CreateProcess(
    NULL,
    "C:\\matlab.exe -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r \"run('C:\\main.m');\"",
    NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL,
    NULL,   // starting directory (NULL means same dir as parent)
    &si, &pi
  );

  if (res == FALSE) printf("CreateProcess failed\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using the [MATLAB Engine API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-engine.html).